# How to plot a parametric curve without using `plot3d_parametric_line`

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

The idea is to plot the curve: `C(t) = (1 + cos(t))i + (1 + sin(t))j + (1 -sin(t)-cos(t))k`. Following the instructions on the Plot Module at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html one can get it using `plot3d_parametric_line`:

Method 1:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from sympy import cos, sin
from sympy.plotting import plot3d_parametric_line
t = sp.symbols('t',real=True)
plot3d_parametric_line(1 + cos(t), 1 + sin(t), 1-sin(t)-cos(t), (t, 0, 2*sp.pi))
```

[image]

Though this is a valid method there is another way to plot it without using `plot3d_parametric_line` but `ax.plot`. What I have tried:

Method 2:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim([-0.15, 2.25])
ax.set_ylim([-0.15, 2.25])
ax.set_zlim([-0.75, 2.50])

ax.plot(1+sp.cos(t),1+sp.sin(t),1-sp.sin(t)-sp.cos(t))
plt.show()
```

But `TypeError: object of type 'Add' has no len()` comes up...

How can I fix it so that I get the same curve than with method 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 3d plotting from `matplotlib` after defining a linear NumPy mesh and computing your x, y, z variables

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
x = 1 + np.cos(t)
y = 1 + np.sin(t)
z = 1 - np.sin(t) - np.cos(t)

ax.plot(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

[image]